# Why does field_get_items() sometimes return "blank"

Tags: entities, media, wysiwyg

`field_get_items('node', $my_node_object, 'field_[fieldname]')` is returning the string 'blank'. Not an array, not NULL, but a string reading 'blank'. It's causing errors in media_wysiwyg module. What causes this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the function's source code it seems that the only way to return 'blank' is when the field's value for the selected langcode is actually 'blank':

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7

I suggest you to use XDdebug to check the node_object value just before this function is called. You can also use a dirty-and-quick trick: edit the code function and add a dpm (but remember to revert it!). But with XDebug you really can see where that 'blank' value comes from.

Comment: The error is happening during a migration so I'm using `dd()` rather than `dpm()` but yeah, that's essentially what I'm doing. I think the word "blank" is coming from my migration somewhere, given that `field_get_items()` doesn't introduce it. Thanks!